# Access Management Containerization

Tags: access-management, sites-10

Is it possible to create a docker container for access management instead of using dedicated machines. If possible; please share some references on this.

Comment: How you can configure this is largely general Docker knowledge. Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely possible. As a matter of fact, we are using (Alpine Linux based) Docker Containers for both Access Management and Add-ons Service for internal testing purposes and in our RWS Cloud offerings.

Example Dockerfile for Access Management:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine3.16

ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add netcat; \
    apk add icu-libs; \
    apk add icu-data-full; \
    chmod +x ./containerBootstrap.sh

# Disable the invariant mode (set in base image)
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

ENTRYPOINT ./containerBootstrap.sh
```